# Storing date when MM and YY are optional

Tags: mysql

I have an input for date. The format is `YYYY-MM-DD`. However, `MM` and `DD` are optional. All the following constitute for expected format:

- 2012-10-13
- 2012-09
- 2010

I need to store this data in MySQL database. It is going to be used for both: to display date and to filter (query) results.

What is the way to do it?

Comment: MM-DD can be stored as 00-00 AFAIK.

Comment: @TheJumpingFrog: [Nope](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/datetime.html): *As of 5.0.2, the server requires that month and day values be legal, and not merely in the range 1 to 12 and 1 to 31, respectively.*

Comment: @Jon, in `TIMESTAMP` values, 0 day/month is illegal, but it is perfectly legal in `DATETIME`.

Comment: @bfrohs: The manual seems to disagree?

Comment: @Jon, then the manual is wrong. I have living proof of this in my MySQL 5.1 database.

Comment: @bfrohs: The section on SQL modes reveals that you need to have the `NO_ZERO_IN_DATE` mode set for the restriction to apply (although there is no mention of this in the date/time types page!).

Comment: @Jon, yes, that's it! I had thought there was some option for that somewhere, but didn't have time to look. I'll add it to my answer :)

Comment: @guy, did one of us answer your question? If so, could you accept the one that was the most correct/helpful? Thanks! (see [How do I ask questions here? in FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply set the month/day to `00` in a `DATETIME` column. For example:

```
2012-04-06
2012-04-00
2012-00-00
```

All of those examples are perfectly valid in `DATETIME` columns. As working proof, we (the company I work for) use this to specify book's published dates for our website. We're currently on MySQL 5.1.54.

***Note:** Depending on the language used to format dates (if any), you may need to format them differently depending on whether day/month is provided. For example, in PHP, I needed to check if the day was provided, and manually change the last '-00' to '-01', and then format the date appropriately (leaving out the day in the final result).*

### From the Manual ([source](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-types.html))

Thanks to @jon for tracking this down:

> MySQL permits you to store dates where the **day or month and day are zero in a `DATE` or `DATETIME` column**. This is extremely useful for applications that need to store birthdates for which you may not know the exact date. In this case, you **simply store the date as '2009-00-00' or '2009-01-00'**. If you store dates such as these, you should not expect to get correct results for functions such as DATE_SUB() or DATE_ADD() that require complete dates. To disallow zero month or day parts in dates, enable the NO_ZERO_IN_DATE SQL mode.

Answer (score 1):

You can store the year, month and day in separate columns and combine them for display. For some queries, you may not need to combine them, e.g. searching for a year.

Answer (score 0):

save in mysql  in `varchar (10 ) NOT NULL` column

and when you retrieve the data use  mysql function `STR_TO_DATE()` or `DATE_FORMAT()`

[`Reference`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html)

Comment: That won't be very friendly for indexing.